PdfLatex changed behaviour
I have just  updated pdflatex to  3.141592653-2.6-1.40.26 (MiKTeX 24.4). Since the day I started using TeX 30+ years ago up to today, the console output of the engine were always the page numbers side-by-side, like [1][2][3][4] and so on. But since the update now the console output is one page per line, like
   [1]
   [2]
   [3]
   [4]

Is this supposed to happen? Is there a reason for it?

yes, it is supposed to happen. I'll see if I can find it ....

There was an update to a marks mechanism, as a consequence a new line was emitted in the log after each page. I think it was mentioned in a recent ltnews. I think it makes the log easier to read

https://www.latex-project.org/news/latex2e-news/ltnews39.pdf page 2 footnote 2 (right hand column) note to l3build users. (but this can't be where I read it - I never read latex news. at least, I never read the typeset version.)

@daleif but it makes the console impossible to read. now I have to actually open the file .... ;)

@cfr pdflatex filename  | perl -pe 's/\]\n/]/' - will wrap every line on the console that ends with ]

@cfr I compile using latexmk -pvc in a terminal so I always see the "log"

Just out of curiosity,  why "impossible to read"?  Today in Linux there are several terminal emulators that allow scrolling the output and text wrapping, so the output can be still read perfectly (really better).  In other OS I guess that it should be equivalent terminal emulators.

@Fran when there are many pages (for example a beamer presentation with a lot of overlays) then with the new output you will see only the line numbers and all other interesting information will quickly scroll out of view. Of course you can scroll back or even search in the terminal etc. but that is much less convenient than seeing the output within the currently visible part of the terminal like in the old behavior.

If the problem is the speed of the output to fully enjoy all the warnings in real time:   pdflatex foo | awk '{ system("sleep 0.3") ; print}' or pdflatex foo | less  to go and back at your own rhythm.

@Fran because with unlimited scroll back I run out of resources and linux kills my emulator completely to protect core processes. but also because I am not good with vim and haven't yet figured out how to scroll in a term in a buffer. and, yes, less works, but I forget to do it.

@DavidCarlisle perl ....

@cfr if you have a real term buffer you can just enter normal mode (via <C-\><C-n>) and then use normal normal mode movements like { or k to scroll up.

@cfr I'd have used sed but I thought someone would complain
